# SCRIPT1005: Expected '(' Error in user.asp

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

In a project of mine hosted in server when I load one page gives me this error in

> SCRIPT1005: Expected '('
>   File: users.asp, Line: 3, Column: 19

in the code I have this

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function datatable-users_onclick() {
}
 // -->
</script>
```

but I can't figure where's missing the '(' like the error says...

**EDITED:**
user.asp file

```html
<!-- #include file="common/header.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="common/_db.asp" -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function datatable_users_onclick() {
}
</script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Colaborador</h2>
        <br/>
        <table class="table dt-responsive" id="datatable-users" onclick="return datatable_users_onclick()">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User-NT</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Acção</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="userAddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" action="user_save.asp" id="userAdd">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Novo Colaborador</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Username:</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="username" id="username" maxlength="50" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Nome Completo:</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="fullname" id="fullname" maxlength="50" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Departmento:</p>
                    <select class="form-control" name="department" id="department" required>
                        <% GetDepartments %>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Papel:</p>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="role" checked>Colaborador</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="role">Admin</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% 
Sub GetDepartments
    Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Departments")
    If Not RS.EOF Then
        Do Until RS.EOF
            departmentId = RS("id")
            departmentName = RS("department")
            Response.Write "<option value=" & departmentId & ">" & departmentName & "</option>"
        RS.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    RS.Close
End Sub
%>

<!-- #include file="common/footer.asp" -->
```

Comment: You have html comment inside javascript tag, change <!-- with /* and //--> with */ and see if problem disappear..

Comment: I figure that and remove. But the problem persists...

Comment: removed comments (<!-- ) or not  ?

Comment: @Max That could be totally normal. in 90's we used to wrap JS inside an HTML comment to prevent issues with older browsers (Netscape 1.0) that doesn't understand it. Now it's useless but it didn't harm. Though OP shouldn't mix JS comment and HTML comment : `// -->`

Comment: And is this really the line 3 of _users.asp_ ? It seems it's not a JS issue but an ASP issue, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @vard i am aware of it  that's why they comes default in some editor during create a internal script tag like in eclipse

Comment: The server-side error will not point to the code you posted, only code between `<% %>` tags is relevant, this is client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Show the code for `users.asp` and we will show you where the error actually lies. Chances are though that if the error is gone you have inadvertently fixed it.

Comment: @Lankymart I edited the post. Add the code asked

Comment: Is the code still erroring? Going off your latest edit the only ASP code block is near the bottom the `Sub GetDepartments()` and line 3 would be `Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Departments")` did you have a missing opening bracket after `Conn.Execute` perhaps that caused the original error?

Comment: I can't remember though off the top of my head if `#includes` will throw as an error in the main page `user.asp` or whether it references the `#include` file-name when an error is thrown. So maybe check line 3 of `header.asp` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a variable/function with any letter, $, or _ character. As long as it doesn't start with a number, you can include numbers as well.

Start: `[a-z], $, _`

Contain: `[a-z], [0-9], $, _`

your are using "-" which is invalid use _ instead

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function datatable_users_onclick() {
}

</script>
```

Comment: Ok in fact in console the error doesn´t appear anymore. I have another error... can't get the datatables...
Thanks @Shailendra

Comment: @KikoFHM That maybe one issue but that isn't why you got a server-side error `SCRIPT1005: Expected '(' File: users.asp, Line: 3, Column: 19`. The problem is you haven't shown the server-side code `<% %>` at line 3 but somewhere in it you have an open bracket without a closing one!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a hyphen. It should be `datatable_users_onclick()`
 instead of
 `datatable-users_onclick()`.

Comment: you are right. In console the error doesn't show no more.

Comment: True but that doesn't explain the server-side error, they posted in the code. You just happened to stop a client-side issue. Also @KikoFHM if you ASP script fails due to an error the client-side script will never be output to the browser, that is why the console will not show the JavaScript function name issue.

Comment: I think this is due to the parser not being able to determine if it is serverside script or clientside (remember we are talking classic asp here)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of not understanding the difference between *Server-Side* and *Client-Side* code.

The error you receive

> SCRIPT1005: Expected '('
>   File: users.asp, Line: 3, Column: 19

is coming from the ASP Engine while the script is being executed by the Server and due to an error exits the script and sends an error response *(`HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`)* to the Client *(Internet Browser)*.

Depending on where your HTML is outputted in the ASP script it's likely that

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function datatable-users_onclick() {
}
 // -->
</script>
```

is never outputted to the client *(hence [no error in the Client console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411130/script1005-expected-error-in-user-asp/33412160#comment54613383_33411250))*.

All the answers about client-side JavaScript function name being incorrect are right but completely irrelevant as the error occurs before any response is sent to the Client.

The error will lie in one of the ASP code blocks `<% %>` that equates to Line 3. It's likely you have a function or sub procedure call that has a missing opening bracket `(` for example or a `Response.Write()` statement that has gone awry.